# Riemann integrable function on each compact

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[a,b]$ which is Riemann integrable on each $[\alpha,\beta]\subset ]a,b[$

How to prove that f is Riemann integrable on [a,b]?

using sum of Darboux

Comment: Split your interval  into 3 parts $[a, a+\epsilon], [a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon], [b-\epsilon, b] $. If $|f|<M$ then you can see that difference between upper and lower Darboux sums on first and third intervals is not more than $2M\epsilon $ each. For the second interval the function is integrable and so the difference between dardboux sums can be made small. Expand this into a proper proof with all the details (not a difficult task).

Answer (score 0):

The (usual) way of thinking is, if you only have information about 
  the tiny compact intervals, try to express your current problem, in
  this case showing that a *global* integral exists, in terms of the
  integrals on the tiny compact intervals.

We'll show that 
  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{\int_{a+1/n}^{b-1/n}}f=\overline{\int_a^b}f$.

Since $f$ is bounded, the upper integral exists,
  that is, the upper integral is a real number.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By the  definition of upper integral, there's a $\delta>0$ 
  such that if
  $$
    P=\{t_0=a<t_1<\dots<t_n=b\}
  $$
  is a partition of $[a,b]$ with $\operatorname{diam}(P)<\delta$, we have
  $$
    U_P-\overline{\int_a^b}f < \varepsilon
    .
  $$

Let $n$ be such that $a<a+1/n<t_1$ and $t_{n-1}<b-1/n<b$. Next we apply
  the definition of the upper integral for a smaller compact interval. For
  $\varepsilon$ there's a $\delta'>0$ such that for any partition $P'$ of
  the interval $[a-1/n,b+1/n]$ we have
  $$
    U_{P'}-\overline{\int_{a+1/n}^{b-1/n}}f < \varepsilon
    .
  $$

Take $\eta=\min\{\delta,\delta'\}$ and let $Q$ be the older partition $P$
  with (a finite amount) of dummy points added so that 
  $\operatorname{diam}(Q)<\eta$. Similarly, let $Q'=Q\cup\{a+1/n,b-1/n\}$.
  Note that 
  $$
    |U_Q-U_{Q'}|\leq M[(t_1-(a+1/n))+(a+1/n-a) + b-1/n-t_{n-1}+b-(b+1/n)]
    =M[t_1-a]+M[b-t_{n-1}]\leq 2\eta M
    ,
  $$
  where $M$ is a bound for $|f|$.

Finally, we estimate the difference
  $$
    \Big|\overline{\int_a^b}f-\overline{\int_{a-1/n}^{b-1/n}}f\Big|
    \leq \Big|\overline{\int_a^b}f-U_Q\Big|
    + |U_Q-U_{Q'}|
    + \Big|U_{Q'}-\overline{\int_{a-1/n}^{b-1/n}}f\Big|
    \leq \varepsilon+2\eta M+\varepsilon
    .
  $$

What's left to do is do the same for the lower integral and put all
  the pieces together:
  $$
    \overline{\int_a^b}f=\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{\int_{a+1/n}^{b-1/n}}f
    =\lim_{n\to\infty}\underline{\int_{a+1/n}^{b-1/n}}f=\underline{\int_a^b}f
    .
  $$

I'll leave the trimming and decoration (adding details, I mean) of the above *sketch* to you.

Comment: the definition I know of riemann integrability is $[\sum_{I=1}^n m_i(x_i-x_{I-1})]-[\sum_{I=1}^n M_i(x_i-x_{I-1})]<\varepsilon$, with $m_i=\inf_{[x_{I-1},x_i]}f(x)$ and $M_i=\sup_{[x_{I-1},x_i]}f(x)$so I don't understand what you do @EBO

Comment: @lindaOiladali According to your definition, a function $f$ is Riemann integrable if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $P$ is a partition whose diameter is less than $\delta$ we have
$$
\Big|\sum_{i=1}^n m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})-\sum_{i=1}^n M_i(x_i-x_{i-1})\Big|<\varepsilon
$$
with the $m_i$ and $M_i$ as you said.

Comment: @lindaOiladali In the proof above I used the fact that... A function $f$ is Riemann integrable (according to the definition above) if and only if
$$
\overline{\int_a^b}f=\underline{\int_a^b}f
$$
where $\overline{\int_a^b}f$ denotes the upper integral and the underlined one denotes the lower integral. The upper integral is simply the infimum over all the possible upper sums. Similarly, the lower integral is the supremum over all the possible lower sums.